# How to upgrade django registration

Tags: django, registration

I'm using django registration v0.7 on my server. I want to upgrade it to v0.8.

As far as I know, I can just run the setup.py in the downloaded file. But then I want to keep the old version 0.7 as a fallback. If the new version doesn't work, I can just downgrade it to v0.7.

Can you kindly tell me how to do it in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

Use setuptools or pip, eg:

```
easy_install django-registration==0.8
```

back to 0.7:

```
easy_install django-registration==0.7
```